# Finding eigenvalues if trace and determinant of the matrix is given

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

> Let $A$  be a  $3\times 3$ matrix with real entries such that $\det(A)=6$ and $tr(A)=0$. If $\det(A+I)=0$ ($I$ denotes $3\times 3$ identity matrix), then the eigenvalues of $A$ are:
>   (i) $-1,2,3$;
>   (ii) $-1,2,-3$;
>   (iii) $1,2,-3$;
>   (iv) $-1,-2,3$.

If a,b,c are 3 eigenvalues then a+b+c=0 and abc=6 because sum of eigen values is trace and product is the determinant value. Then how to apply $\det(A+I)$?

Comment: Sos de la facultad de ingeniería?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eigen values of $A+I$ are obtained by adding $1$ to  the eigenvalues of $A$. So $\det(A+I)=0$ gives a third condition on them (besides $\det A = 6, \ \mathrm{tr\,}A=0$) and that should enable you to find the answer.

Comment: If a,b,c are eigen values of A then a+1,b+1,c+1 are eigen values of A+I.Am i right? then we have a+b+c=0, abc=6 and (a+1)(b+1(c+1)=0.IS it possible to solve these equation to find a,b,and c.

Comment: Expand the  product $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=0$ fully then the solution will emerge.

Answer (score 2):

In the above question option (iv) is correct.
Sum of eigenvalues is $0$
product of eigenvalues is $6$
(ie) $a+b+c =0$ and $abc=6$
and also $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=0$ since $\det(A+I)=0$
Solving we get the roots.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Check the following: for a $\;3\times 3\;$ matrix $\;A\;$, and putting $\;\Delta:=\det A\;,\;\;\mathcal T:=tr. A\;$ , we have that its characteristic polynomial is

$$x^3-\mathcal T x^2+\left(\mathcal T^2-tr.\left(A^2\right)\right)x-\Delta$$

Comment: @ DonAnatonio: Is the coefficient of $x^2$ really the determinant?

Comment: Good catch, @PVanchinathan: it is *minus* the trace. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler than this; $\det(A+I) = 0$ means that one of the eigenvalues must equal $-1$, so without loss of generality we can say $a = -1$; the other two bits of information then become $bc = -6, b+c=1$. So: $a=-1, b=-2, c=3$